# Key of size 7 not supported by this algorithm. Only keys of size 24 supported

Tags: php

I'm using `mcrypt_encryp`t function and it's return empty value.
My code this is:

```
$secret = 'der102rtv1';
$data = '24000441;82;100';
$key = base64_decode($secret);
$blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
$len = strlen($data);
$pad = $blockSize - ($len % $blockSize);
$data .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
$encrypt = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb'));
```

PHP Version 5.6.33 and this code return empty what is problem?

UPDATE:
I have this error:
Warning: mcrypt_encrypt(): Key of size 7 not supported by this algorithm. Only keys of size 24 supported

Comment: Have you looked in your logs? Any warnings popping up?

Comment: I have warning Update my question

Comment: Have you tried a longer key?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not return *empty*, it returns `bool(false)`. As per [the docs](http://php.net/mcrypt_encrypt) that means *failure*.

According to Wikipedia, the [Triple DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) algorithm supports three [key options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options) (emphasis mine):

- *Keying option 1*
  All three keys are independent. Sometimes known as 3TDEA or triple-length keys.
  This is the strongest, with 3 × 56 = 168 independent key bits. It is still vulnerable to meet-in-the-middle attack, but the attack requires 22 × 56 steps.
- *Keying option 2*
  K1 and K2 are independent, and K3 = K1. Sometimes known as 2TDEA or double-length keys.
  This provides a shorter key length of 112 bits and a reasonable compromise between DES and Keying option 1, with the same caveat as above.[15] This is an improvement over "double DES" which only requires 256 steps to attack. **NIST has deprecated this option.**
- *Keying option 3*
  All three keys are identical, i.e. K1 = K2 = K3.
  This is backward compatible with DES, since two operations cancel out. **ISO/IEC 18033-3 never allowed this option, and NIST no longer allows it**.

  Each DES key is 8 odd-parity bytes, with 56 bits of key and 8 bits of error-detection. A **key bundle requires 24 bytes for option 1**, 16 for option 2, or 8 for option 3.

The error message asks for 24 bytes worth of keys and the only option that is not deprecated is the only one that requires 24 bytes. That suggests that mcrypt doesn't support the NIST-deprecated keying options. But none of the options support a key bundle size of 7 bytes so  it's kind of unclear what you're trying to accomplish in the first place:

- If you want to mimic the encryption method of some third-party application or technology in order to decrypt already encrypted data, you need to gather more information about the exact algorithm and parameters used.
- If you just want to encrypt fresh data for your own consumption you may want to try a library that isn't abandoned and possibly switch to an algorithm that doesn't have known vulnerabilities. The state-of-the-art encryption library in PHP is [Sodium](http://php.net/Sodium), available since PHP/7.2, but [OpenSSL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) is also a good alternative that's been available since PHP/5.3

... or just try a longer key.

Answer (score -1):

First argument of `mcrypt_encrypt` function should be the one of the `MCRYPT_` constants, so maybe that's your problem.
Check the manual for this: http://php.net/manual/es/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php

Comment: From the docs you link to `One of the MCRYPT_ciphername constants, or the name of the algorithm as string.`

Comment: You're right. I didn't remember 'tripledes' as one of the existing algorithms. Thanks for the correction! @JonStirling